# What's the name for the pen and ink drawing style seen in J. J. Grandville's art?

Tags: technique-identification, style-identification

I don't know much about art history or different drawing traditions, but I often see this style of line art (done in pen and ink I think?) which uses many thin lines for shading. Some examples of what I'm talking about include:

| [image] | [image] |
| --- | --- |
| J. J. Grandeville, [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_Ignace_Isidore_G%C3%A9rard_Grandville#/media/File:Grandville_leLoup_Et_Le_Chien.jpg) | John Tenniel, [source](https://medium.com/alice-s-adventures-in-wonderland/sir-john-tenniel-s-classic-illustrations-of-alice-in-wonderland-2c3bbdca3a77) |
| [image] | [image] |
| A hand, [source](https://nl.pinterest.com/pin/481181541439349656/) | Some animals, [source](https://www.123rf.com/photo_77007446_animals-around-the-world-collection-of-an-hand-drawn-illustrations-freehand-sketches-line-art-drawin.html) |

I never know how to describe this style of drawing and search for more examples. I'm also not sure if there's a term for this style of art, or if I'm grouping together unrelated art styles, but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi ink, do note that the characteristic you're looking for is part of the technique, and not an artistic style. I've added the technique-identification tag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The kind of shading with many thin lines is called [hatching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hatching).

[image]
([image source](https://www.shoorayner.com/how-to-shade-drawings-with-cross-hatching/crosshatch2/))

It's very common in ink or pen drawings and printing techniques like [etching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etching) or [woodblock printing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodblock_printing). A sub-category of prints with especially fine details is the "[old master print](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_master_print)".

[This site](https://www.vangoghgenova.it/this-hatching-exercise-will-make-your-drawings-better.html) demonstrates a number of different hatching techniques and how they influence our perception of the shapes

Comment: Oh this is very helpful, thank you!