# When drawing what is the name of these textures and patterns?

Tags: drawing, terminology

Is there a name for drawing/painting by texture and pattern naming?

For example naming that goes along with these patterns and expands further?

[image]

I would ask for a specific book but I believe that is off topic for this site.

Comment: [This question](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/10169/whats-the-name-for-the-pen-and-ink-drawing-style-seen-in-j-j-grandvilles-art) is related (and a partial duplicate).

Answer (score 5):

**Hatching and Crosshatching techniques**

Different types of hatching and crosshatching:

- Scribble hatching: overlapping circles or squiggles. This leaves a rough organic feel and texture
- Hatching: Parallel lines to fill in a tone
- Patch hatching: Creating small interlacing lines, varying in angle (that look like a patch)
- Cross hatching: Similar to the patch hatching, but avoiding 90° angles while interlacing lines, staying with acute line angles.
- Contour hatching: Instead of keeping the lines parallel, you wrap the lines around, like a curved surface. As you draw, the lines will wrap around the curved surface.

Source: https://johnmuirlaws.com/hatching-and-crosshatching-technique/