# How is this style called and how is it done?

Tags: painting, drawing, style-identification, portrait-drawing

I am wondering, what is the historical origin, technique and name of the following drawing/painting style, done by means of little dots and nets. Or is it perhaps the effect of the drawing support or maybe some kind of digitalization artifact?

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I did not put the image directly because I am not sure of the copyright of it

Comment: It's an old image of Henry III - the original is probably in the public domain. While reproductions might not be, I think for educational use this is allowed. I tried looking for the artist, but no luck so far.

Comment: Related: [Why did they make shadows with stripes?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/q/11971/), [What's the name for the pen and ink drawing style seen in J. J. Grandville's art?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/q/10169/), [When drawing, what is the name of these textures and patterns?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/q/10871/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's probably an **engraving**, a printing technique with which an original image is engraved onto a metal (often copper) plate using a burin.
It could also be an **etching**, whereby an image is etched into a protective layer on a metal plate, after which an acid is used to carve out the exposed areas. Etchings tend to have slightly blurry lines, because the lines are more irregular, but especially with reproductions it is often hard to distinguish.

The lines, or "nets", are a technique called [*hatching*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hatching), a common method to get tonality and a sense of shape.
The dots are a less common technique known as [*stippling*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stippling), used similarly to get tonality (like e.g. [halftone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halftone)). I find it is often used for softer and/or lighter materials, like skin, to contrast it with the rougher appearance of hatching.

A known consequence of digitizing prints with regular patterns is spatial aliasing. This might happen with the pattern in the background, but it looks authentic.